# Насколько ALTER SEQUENCE является дорогой операцией?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется следующий `sequence`:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE some_seq START 100000;
```

и следующая таблица, которая его использует:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_entities
(
    id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('some_seq'),
    some_data TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```

Я хочу сделать оптимизацию генерации `primary key` при вставке новых сущностей пакетами. Для этого я хочу генерировать ключ прямо в коде *(сделать аналог `allocation size` из Hibernate)*.

Принцип работы будет следующий:

1. Делаю шаг инкремента в `some_seq` в 50 вместо 1.
2. При вставке нового пакета делаю запрос `nextval()` к БД, получаю значение, и инкрементирую его прямо в коде. Если значение при инкрементации достигает 50, то я делаю ещё один запрос `nextval()` и продолжаю работать уже со вторым значением *(это делается для того, чтобы не было пересечений по первичным ключам при параллельном обращении к базе данных)*.
3. Вставляю новые сущности со сгенерированными первичными ключами.

Возникает следующий вопрос. Для такой реализации мне необходим следующий `sequence`:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE user_seq START 100000 INCREMENT 50;
```

но мне будет не очень удобно им пользовать в остальное время, когда я не делаю вставку пакетами, потому что при обычной вставке записей между первичными ключами будут огромные пробелы.

Так вот, а что если я всегда буду пользоваться обычным `sequence`, а перед вставкой пакета выполнять операцию

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE user_seq INCREMENT 50;
```

и после выполнения операции:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE user_seq INCREMENT 1;
```

Насколько `ALTER SEQUENCE` является дорогой операцией? Не убьёт ли он всю производительность от генерации первичных ключей в коде?

Comment: *Я хочу сделать оптимизацию генерации primary key при вставке новых сущностей пакетами. Для этого я хочу генерировать ключ прямо в коде* Получить профит от такой "оптимизации" - практически без шансов.

Comment: @Akina ну, видимо, разработчики Hibernate (java фреймворк) об этом не знали, так как они сделали возможность такой оптимизации. Может быть вы не так меня поняли?

Суть оптимизации в том, что при вставке нескольких сущностей nextval не дёргается, т.к. сущности вставляются с уже готовыми id, сгенерированными в коде.

Comment: *они сделали возможность такой оптимизации* И что, отключение этой "оптимизации", дающее возможность сравнения, показывает устойчиво определяемую более высокую производительность при генерации в коде? ЕМНИП в Hibernate это не оптимизация, а попытка загрести себе абсолютно всю логику, а из сервера БД сделать тупое хранилище.

Comment: @Akina я лично не замерял. Ну и к тому же hibernate не забирает логику по генерации id полностью, потому что sequence в бд по-прежнему остаётся и так же дёргается, только теперь реже в 50 раз.

Comment: @Zhenyria (1) в новых постгрисах есть тип поля `SERIAL`, который является аналогом авто-инкрементных ИД в других базах. (2) Причём в Постгрисе он как раз уже заимплемеентирован батчами - как только коннекшн пытается сгенерировать ключ, ему сразу выделяют 20 штук и он тратит из этого диапазона (3) " ну, видимо, разработчики Hibernate (java фреймворк) об этом не знали, так как они сделали возможность такой оптимизации." неуместный сарказм. Хибернэйт пытается работать со всеми базами данных, и для некоторых такая оптимизация была уместна, в том числе и для старых Постгрисов без `SERIAL`

Comment: Хотя нет, по дефолту не выделяет заранее. Но можно включить preallocation aka cache, напишу как ответ.

Comment: Гуглите по термину HiLo (Hi/Lo).

Answer (score 1):

Кэширование лучше включить на уровне Постгриса, тогда он при первом обращении будет выделять сессии диапазон значений, из которого сессия может тратить не обращаясь к базе

Два способа

```
create table t1 (
  id serial
);
alter sequence t1_id_seq CACHE 50; -- говорим Постгрису кэшировать 50 значений
```

или

```
create sequence ids as integer CACHE 50;  -- говорим Постгрису кэшировать 50 значений
create table t2 (
  id integer not null default nextval('ids')
)
```

Comment: "не обращаясь к базе" - это не так работает, значения кешируются в памяти сервера БД без обращения к диску (которое к слову и так кешируется два раза - буферный кеш и кеш ОС). Обращения к БД из приложения все равно будут и это решение никак не поможет убрать сетевые запросы к постгресу (вероятно, в них у автора будет основной затык).

Comment: Если ИД выделять на клиенте, то будут обращения к серверу. А если выделять на сервере, то будет использоваться память сессии, без обращения к базе. Под обращением к базе я имею ввиду модификацию счётчика sequence и все связанные с этим расходы.